# Working with variables in an Excel formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I am aware that

```
Cells(16, 2) = "=TEXT(42831,""dd-mmm-yy"")"  'DISPLAYS 06-Apr-17 IN CELL B16
```

The macro I'm working on needs the Date Serial Number, namely 42831, to be replaced with a variable:-

```
 Dim lngDateSerialNo As Long
 lngDateSerialNo = 42831
```

So now I have assigned 42831 to the variable, `lngDateSerialNo`.
It's not really relevant here but just to say that this variable will be updated during run time to give me a desired sequence of dates spaced one week apart.

I am also aware that

```
Cells(18, 2) = "=TEXT(" & lngDateSerialNo & ",""dd-mmm-yy"")" 'displays 06-Apr-17 IN cell B18
```

and to be fair I needed help with the above line of code.

OBJECTIVE

To try an understand what exactly the Ampersand is doing - apart from giving me the result I want!

Being relatively inexperienced in VBA, my understanding of the Ampersand is that it is a Concatenation operator and doesn't appear to have any other function in life.

Question 1
Could someone out there please give me an understanding as to why that line of code works so well?

Question 2
Purely academic, but if indeed the Ampersand is a concatenation operator, can the CONCATENATE formula be used in place of the ampersand?

Answer (score 4):

> my understanding of the Ampersand is that it is a Concatenation operator and doesn't appear to have any other function in life

Basically yes, unless you want to also consider the `&` being used as a type specifier for `Long`:

```
Dim a&  ' declares a As Long
```

> Could someone out there please give me an understanding as to why that line of code works so well?

Because that *is* the way to write this kind of code.
The only change you can potentially make is to replace the `&` with a `+` which works like `&` if both arguments are strings, but you shouldn't do that because `&` expresses the intent in the clearest way.

> Purely academic, but if indeed the Ampersand is a concatenation operator, can the CONCATENATE formula be used in place of the ampersand

No, because that particular `&` is a part of the VBA syntax. You are building a string in VBA, it does not matter at this point that the string contains an Excel formula. VBA does not have a `CONCATENATE` function so you can't use it in place of the `&` when building a string in VBA.

However the `&` is also used for string concatenation in the Excel formula syntax, and if you were to build a formula with a `&` inside the double quotes, not outside, you could replace it with `CONCATENATE`, because now it's the Excel syntax where `CONCATENATE` exists.